How to implement a Javascript confirm dialog in Selenium JavascriptExecutor
Is it possible to return a value from  a Javascript confirm dialog via Selenium JavascriptExecutor ?
so the test code can determine if tester clicks OK or Cancel ?
I tried this code:
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    String result =
        (String)
            js.executeScript(
                "var confirmed = confirm('Press a button Either OK or Cancel'); return confirmed ? 'true' : 'false';");

   WebDriverWait waitForAlert = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
   waitForAlert.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())); 

   System.out.println("Confirmed: " + result);  // null

Seems like the confirm dialog is running asynchronously so
assignment for the return variable happens before the dialog has returned anything.

when you assign the results of a script to a var like this it should wait for the promise to return.  I think it's the "?" in your script that is causing the issue.  You should just use "return confirmed;"  I think "??" is null coalescer...  but is not needed here.  It should return true if user chose "OK", otherwise it'll be false.

I tried a few variations of that including ?? but the return is always executing immediately: a confirm popup is normally a modal window but apparently not when called by executeScript:  looks like the return needs to be wrapped in a promise .

I tried using a promise but I don't think that's possible with a standard js confirm popup

the driver may not expect you to launch a prompt, so I guess it isn't waiting.  Maybe just launch a prompt in your native code there.

WebDriverWait waitForAlert works as intended. Native coded confirm is a good suggestion. First I'm trying a custom js confirm dialog injected from selenium

No such problem for an injected custom js confirm dialog, so that's the workaround
